# raise RuntimeError(f'Cannot parse version {FULLVERSION}') in install MKL with numpy from WSL

Tags: python, numpy, intel-mkl

I tried to link MKL with numpy in Windows subsystem Linux
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/build-numpy-with-mkl-and-icc.html

In step 4, I modified `site.cfg`, `numpy/distutils/intelccompiler.py`, and `/numpy /distutil /fcompiler /intel.py`,

in `python setup.py config --compiler=intelem build_clib --compiler=intelem build_ext --compiler=intelem install`

I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "setup.py", line 60, in <module>
   raise RuntimeError(f'Cannot parse version {FULLVERSION}')
RuntimeError: Cannot parse version 0+unknow
```

Do I have to install `ifort` to use `numpy` with `MKL`? How to solve the above error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation that you are referring to is an outdated one. Intel is currently including Intel MKL optimized packages along with Intel Distribution for Python.

Prebuilt packages of Intel MKL optimized NumPy and SciPy are available to use through pip and conda channels. You could install the latest versions of these packages with pip/conda package manager if you have either of them installed. Please find the multiple options available, with installation commands in the below links:

https://anaconda.org/intel/scipy

https://anaconda.org/intel/numpy

Alternatively, you could also get these packages along with other Intel optimized python packages by downloading and installing the standalone Intel Distribution for Python or the complete Intel oneAPI Base Toolkit (which includes Intel Distribution for Python along with other Intel optimized tools) from the below links:

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/oneapi-standalone-components.html#python

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/base-toolkit.html

All the above-mentioned options are available free of cost. Since you are installing inside Windows Subsystem for Linux, make sure to download and install the Linux versions of Intel Distribution for Python or Intel oneAPI Base Toolkit inside the WSL shell.

Comment: Thanks. I tried conda install -c intel/label/intelnumpy numpy and pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/intel/label/intelnumpy/simple numpy, WSL told me it is already installed. Then, my np.show_config() still gives openblas. I tried Intel® Distribution for Python* for Linux* online, it tells me 'This machine uses operating system "Ubuntu Linux version 16.04". Compatibility issues may occur.',  I click next no result. I tried sudo do-release-upgrade -d, it tells me ... Error in sys.excepthook: ...

Comment: I installed ubuntu-20.04 lts as wsl, and try to install via  Intel® Distribution for Python* for Linux* online, in 
                                        SP
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ y I consent to the collection of my information
[ ] I do NOT c  sent to the collection of my information
 x
xxBegin Installation  Back  Quit, after click enter, it seems the program is running, but there is no progress bar, not sure if i need off-line version

Comment: thankfully, there is a progress bar when using the offline version.

Comment: And I got `Installation Complete | Intel® Distribution for Python*`, how to connect it with numpy? I tried `np.show_config()`, still openblas

Comment: Once you have installed Intel Distribution for Python, did you try setting the environment variables? If not, run the following commands once:
`cd ~` followed by,
`echo 'source intel/oneapi/setvars.sh' >> ~/.bashrc` followed by,
`source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you so much! (though I already used https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/using-intel-distribution-for-python-with-anaconda.html source activate idp and let mkl-numpy works in conda