# how to install numpy and pandas in python 2.7.9 version

Tags: python

how to install numpy and pandas in python 2.7.9 version using command line.
please help with complete installing process.
I have tried in windows 10 OS , but it's not installed . Showing syntax error.
I have used command in python 2.7.9 as below
pip install numpy / python -m pip install numpy
pip install pandas / python -m pip install pandas

Comment: Are you able to install other modules beside numpy or pandas?

Comment: Please describe what commands you have tried and what errors are showing. Btw if you use pip you just need to open a shell and type `pip install numpy pandas`

Comment: Same command i have tried. pip install numpy / pip install pandas

Comment: But it's showing syntax error - Invalid Syntax

Comment: Are you running it from the python interpreter? [Read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Comment: Please help on this. how can i solve this issues ?

Comment: Yes. I am using python enterpreter

Answer (score 0):

make sure you havent opened python interpreter like so
[image]

open command prompt then run the command
also make sure environment variables are set

Comment: what i have to set in environment variable ?

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend you upgrade Python Package otherwise try to find which NumPy version supports python 2.7.9 then install like this `pip install numpy==1.9.2`
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947345/which-numpy-library-is-compatible-with-python-2-7-9]

Comment: which stack overflow email id i can send my complete query

Comment: Please show an error so we can help you more efficiently, Python 2.7.9 support Numpy 1.9.2 version. Share your error so we will resolve your issue within a few minutes.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "c:\users\oxygen08\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Oxygen08\numpy\setup.py", line 59
        raise RuntimeError(f'Cannot parse version {FULLVERSION}')
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: have you seen this error. I am installing this in Windows 10 Pro 64-bit operating system. with command line prompt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69791533/raise-runtimeerrorfcannot-parse-version-fullversion-in-install-mkl-with-nu

Comment: I hope this link solves your problem, error occurs because documentation that you are referring to is outdated.

Comment: Ok. Then i need to install updated version of python and then install numpy & pandas. Please suggest.

Comment: I think this is good for you, the latest version added value to your resume too. Good Luck